# GCE instance -- cannot ping its own external IP

Tags: google-compute-engine

I can ping its external IP from my local laptop, but cannot ping from its own. I have set up firewall rules to allow icmp from all internal IPs of its subnetwork (10.45.0.0/6) . What other reasons could be?

Comment: Did you define an outgoing firewall rule that is blocking ICMP?

Comment: @JohnHanley there's no egress firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCE uses the Hypervisor to assign the External IP to an Instance.

That means the firewall rule applies between the external IP and the Instance and to be able to enable ping lookback, a 0.0.0.0/0 allow rule (or more restrictive) for icmp will allow the ping to reach the external IP from the Internal one. Make sure you have the default firewall rule 'default-allow-icmp' on your network details for the VM. Please see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) for more information about rules in the default network.

Comment: Do you have a reference for `GCE uses the Hypervisor to assign the External IP to an Instance.`? I am very interested in more details in this area.

Comment: This is not documented at the moment due to it being functionality that is proprietary to GCP services. While there is no specific external documentation on how GCP uses the hypervisor, cloud computing is based over virtual Machines being administered by a [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) to reach the bare-metal hosts. An easy check is to read the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) from your Instance.